# Meteor Tracker error after multiple routes

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

When a running a particular route, I'm getting an error (see below), but ONLY if I've run one or more other routes before running this one. It doesn't matter what those other routes are. So if I reload the home page, and then click to this route, no error. But if I reload home, go to any other route, and then the one in question, I get this error:

> Exception from Tracker recompute function: undefined debug.js:43
>   Error: {{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or falsey
>   values.
>       at badSequenceError (http://localhost:3000/packages/observe-sequence.js?hash=550c39b36ab0e65194ea03cdc7ecbe99dcdd07f6:174:10)
>       at http://localhost:3000/packages/observe-sequence.js?hash=550c39b36ab0e65194ea03cdc7ecbe99dcdd07f6:139:17
>       at Object.Tracker.nonreactive (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=f525263111eb9d90f4ce1ad064f97aca4a6c1b07:631:12)
>       at http://localhost:3000/packages/observe-sequence.js?hash=550c39b36ab0e65194ea03cdc7ecbe99dcdd07f6:116:15
>       at Tracker.Computation._compute (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=f525263111eb9d90f4ce1ad064f97aca4a6c1b07:339:36)
>       at new Tracker.Computation (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=f525263111eb9d90f4ce1ad064f97aca4a6c1b07:229:10)
>       at Object.Tracker.autorun (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=f525263111eb9d90f4ce1ad064f97aca4a6c1b07:604:11)
>       at Object.observe (http://localhost:3000/packages/observe-sequence.js?hash=550c39b36ab0e65194ea03cdc7ecbe99dcdd07f6:113:31)
>       at . (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:2763:43)
>       at fireCallbacks (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=ef41aed769a8945fc99ac4954e8c9ec157a88cea:1955:26)
>   undefined

My Router code:

```js
Router.route('/exercises', {

  name: 'exercises',

  waitOn: function() {
    this.exercisesSub = Meteor.subscribe('exercises');
    this.progressSub = undefined;

    if (Meteor.userId() && Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().emails[0].verified) {
      this.progressSub = Meteor.subscribe("progress", Meteor.userId());
    }

    return [this.exercisesSub, this.progressSub];
  },

  data: function() {

    if (this.exercisesSub.ready()) {

      if (this.progressSub === undefined || this.progressSub.ready()) {

        var data = {
          subHeader: 'Exercises',
          exercises: Exercises.find({}, {sort: {order: 1}}),
        };

        if (this.progressSub !== undefined) {
          data.progress = Progress.findOne({});
        }

        return data;
      }
    }
  }

});
```

My HTML:

```html
<template name="exercises">

      {{#each exercises}}

      <exercise id="{{_id}}">
        <h2>{{name}}</h2>
        <completedBox></completedBox><completedBox></completedBox><completedBox></completedBox>
        <description>{{description}}</description>
        <criteria>Criteria: <b>{{criteria}}</b></criteria>
        Highest score: <score>0%</score>
        {{>button name="launch" text="LAUNCH"}}
      </exercise>

      {{/each}}

</template>
```

The returned collection Exercises contains the same data with or without error, but for some reason Meteor doesn't see that data if I've loaded previous routes. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you comment out the `{{#each}}` and output the value of `exercises`?  You should be able to write a quick help and pass the value to `console.log()`

Comment: Ah! In onRender I was settings Template.exercises.exercises to something else, not realizing it was the same 'exercises' in the html. Fixed. Thanks!